# Does anyone know about an app being created to help the Muslim Community keep in touch via mobiles?

Tags: practical-islam, software

Some months ago there was an article in an edition of "SAM", the Sydney [University] Alumni Magazine, which detailed two students who were developing an app, named Ummah or something very similar, which was designed to work with mobiles, and the aim of which being to help the Muslim community keep in touch with each other, to improve the community's sense of social cohesion and support, as well as communication. Does anyone know how this is going, i.e. whether it is ready to be put to practical use yet, or how far away from the stage of being able to be purchased the app is?

Comment: Is it a marketplace or a platform?

Comment: How about this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vbulletin.build_1165 ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the iUmmah app which is still under development. Daily Mail has [a full report regarding this app](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3353650/iUmmah-app-dubbed-Tinder-Muslims.html). The way I see it, it's a app created by the some nationalist fasuq (bad) Muslims to spread nationalism among Muslims. They are taking money from the australian government to which shows they are acting in the interest of australian government not the Muslim ummah. Daily Mail says:

> The trio, all in their 20s, sought a way for Muslim youths to connect
>   with not only their ancestry, but **also to the Australian identity.**

The above quotation means that one of the fundamental target of that app is to spread the toxic idea of nationalism.

Edit: If you are looking for Islamic social media sites than I recommend Muslimface.com and Ummah.com. If you are a Shia Muslim then shiachat.com